# how to get my page in google's,yahoo and other search engines first page?

Tags: seo

i want to list my web page in google,yahoo and other popular search engines first page?what can i do?i am having computer backgruoud? so can you please tell me the ways to SEO? and suggest me if any tutorails need to become well SEO?

Comment: Has been answered here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/

Answer (score 0):

Look into sitemaps. It is how search engines see content changes etc from your site. I would make an account with Google webmaster tools. The information you can get from that is very valuable. Yahoo probably has something similar.

Comment: all the SEO theory and practice in 39 words? :)

Comment: Dont take it as an offense. I was just pointing up that the question is too much generic and cannot be answered in few words

Answer (score 0):

Write content that others find the most valuable and choose to link to from their pages.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your web page in big search engines' first pages is our main goal when we do SEO. In this perspective, your question can be rephrased as how to do a good SEO?

Obviously, you need to do lot of things since whole lot of people out there are working on this, it is not an easy answer to your question.

Content. Its king, no matter how dramatic or frequent Google changes its algorithm, or whatever search engines you are targeting, as long as you have a unique and fresh content, you will be alright.

Code. HTML(Not code, but make sense), URL, as well as other web related stuff. Clear and semantic HTML is very important, which involves mata tags,  tags as others like web structure.

Link. Google made several statement that PR is not considered, but I believe appropriate link is very important.

Keep leaning and do not do something stupid(black hat).